# How to pass values out of reusable PickerView.xib in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xib, viewcontroller, uipicker

I created a reusable `UIPickerView`:

[image]

**PickerView.swift**:

```
class PickerView: UIView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var labels: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PickerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(pickerView)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return labels[row]
    }        
}
```

This code makes it so that I can initialize a `UIPickerView` just by setting the class of a `UIView` to `PickerView`:

[image]

And to add data to the `UIPickerView`, I just create an `outlet` and add data via the outlet. So, my ViewController.swift file looks like this:

**ViewController.swift**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: PickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pickerView.labels = ["Label1","Label2","Label3"]
    }
}
```

---

**Here's my question:** How can I pass the `didSelectRow` value out of the picker to use in ViewController.swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create custom protocol

```
protocol MyPickerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didSelectSomething(some: String)
}
```

create instance inside **PickerView.swift** like

```
weak var myDelegate: MyPickerDelegate?
```

then in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.pickerView.myDelegate = self
```

then make your `UIViewController` conform protocol

```
extension ViewController: MyPickerDelegate {
    func didSelectSomething(some: String) {
       // self.doStuff()
    }
}
```

then inside **PickerView.swift** call `didSelectRow` and inside it

```
self.myDelegate?.didSelectSomething(some: "SomeValue")
```